# SSRS PDF Export Headers Incorrect

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have created a report with several related tables and a couple of charts. It looks **good in Visual Studio** and exports PDF fine but when I deploy to Report Manager and export to PDF, the **headers don't appear** on subsequent pages and the **first row is expanded as if it were the header**. Also, **rows with long names do not expand** the rows as they should.

[image: Stupid PDF Export]

Has anyone had this issue and/or know how to fix it?

I thought I was done with this report until I tried exporting from Report Manager.

Comment: Nope, never seen that. What are your report size and page size properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the issue is due to using **CanGrow** for cells in a tablix exported to **PDF**.

I had tried changing every other property to get it to work then a co-worker said to change the **CanGrow** to **False**. Amazingly it worked! There were no more jacked up first row and the headers magically started repeating.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a crappy workaround to an annoying bug. I either have to cut off some text or have some huge rows to accommodate a few records with long text. The same issue is in SharePoint - I can't believe this issue hasn't come up before.